# Having issues with calling an order insertion method recursively to sort an entire linked list

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, linked-list

I have an Ordered Insertion sort method which sorts an item in a linked list in ascending order as it is been added.

```
 //getData() returns the data in that Node
 //getLink() returns the link to the next Node
 //setLink() sets the link of the Node 
 //top is the reference to the first node

public void ordInsert(int newItem) {

 IntNode prev = null;
 IntNode next = top;
 while(next!=null && next.getData()<newItem){
   prev = next;
   next = next.getLink();
 }
 IntNode newNode = new IntNode(newItem,next);
 if(prev==null)
   top = newNode;
 else
   prev.setLink(newNode);
}
```

I am trying to create a method that sorts the entire list by using this ordered sorting method.
Here is what I have tried

```
  public void inSort(){

     IntNode next = top;

     if(next != null){

       ordInsert(next.getData());
       top.setLink(next.getLink());
       inSort();
     }

   return;
 }
```

Right now it is just an infinite recursive method which crashes my program.
I need to know what I am doing wrong and how to go about it not the code.

```
 Input: 3000 400 40 120 70 
 Expected Output : 40 70 120 400 3000
```

Comment: Can't you just use a `SortedSet` or just call `List.sort()`?

Comment: Could you provide more context? As of now, `ordInsert` calls the `IntNode` constructor with either next pointing to an `IntNode` or being `null`. What does the constructor look like? In `inSort` you are reinserting nodes, am I reading that right? Are the nodes being removed somewhere or this that actually expanding the list? Also you seem to be resetting `top` which ought to point invariably to the top of this list.

Comment: @jgb The IntNode constructor sets the data in the `Node` and the link to the next node. Yes in `inSort` I am reinserting nodes. The `inSort` method is to take all the data in the linked list and re-arrange them in ascending ordr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Tracking the infinite recursion**

The problem you are having now is that the node being sorted into the list is not being removed.

Let's have a look at the example input you provided:

```
Input: 3000 400 40 120 70
```

At the start, `top` is pointing to the `3000` node. In `inSort`, `next` is set to point where `top` points, and `3000` is the value to be inserted.

With the call to `ordInsert`, the initial condition

```
while(next!=null && next.getData()<newItem)
```

is *never* true, because `next.getData()` is always equal to `newItem` (it is the very object you are trying to reinsert!). As a consequence, the `top` node is recreated and inserted at the top and `top` consequently set to point there. Thus, the list is now:

```
3000 3000 400 40 120 70
```

with `top` pointing to the first element.

Since `next` is a reference to the same object as `top`, `top`s link is now set to the `3000` next to it. And you find yourself in the same situation as before, only the list is preceded by another element.

Calling again to `inSort()` will repeat that process indefinitely to yield the result

```
3000 3000 ... 3000 400 40 120 70
```

---

**Issues**

- Elements to be inserted are not removed, leading to an expansion of the list
- Resetting of `top` in `inSort` invalidates the premise for the while loop in `ordInsert`.

**Suggested solution**

The method `ordInsert` only works if the list, the new element gets inserted into, is already sorted. So, the strategy should be:

```
1. Detach element at index 0
2. Sort remaining list
3. insert detached element into sorted list
```

Thus, first save a reference to the top of the list, then advance the `top` marker to the next element and set the detached (previous top) element to point to `null`. That won't invalidate the premise of the while loop because `top` is still referencing the top of the list (the element at index 0 has been *removed* from the list).

Then make the call to `inSort()` of the now shortened list. After a successful call, use `ordInsert()` to insert the detached element. Best to make it work with `IntNode` rather than creating an entirely new element.

For the recursion to work, assert that `top` is referencing the beginning of the list (shortened [after detaching] or extended [after reinserting]) so that for any recursion step, the program's state is valid. And watch out for the base case, when `top == null`.

Comment: Got the idea. But still a bit confused on how to go about it. Could you help with an idea on how to go about it?

Answer (score 0):

In `inSort`, the stop condition is `if(next == null)`. 
`next` is `top` and `top` is the head of the list (not the last node). Therefore, the recursion never stops.

Also, instead of sorting the **existing linked list**, you are inserting **new data**, the code duplicates nodes infinity.